# How to check if value exists in PosrgreSQL enum custom type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

At my PostgreSQL database I have custom enum type called `vegetables_type`. It contains `('carrot', 'potato', 'tomato')` values. My task is to add new value to this type. I am looking for an SQL statement to check if this new value already exists in this type and if not - add this value, if it exists - do nothing.

I've find `SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::vegetables_type));` statement. But I can't find how to operate on this result - it is not possible to apply `WHERE`, `IN`, `ANY` operations.

Answer (score 1):

Move the call to `unnest()` to the FROM clause, then you can use the output like any other table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM unnest(enum_range(NULL::vegetables_type)) as t(name)
WHERE name::text = 'carrot'
```

To test if a value exist, you can use e.g.:

```
select exists (select *
               FROM unnest(enum_range(NULL::vegetables_type)) as t(name)
               WHERE t.name::text = 'new_item')
```

The above will return `true` if `new_item` is already a member of the enum.

---

But you don't need such a complicated statement to begin with. You can simply use `if not exists` as part of the ALTER statement:

```
alter type vegetables_type add value if not exists 'new_item';
```

Comment: wow, this last passage with 'if not exists' is so simple and cool. Thanks